# VueJs getting error from Dynamically array passing as string but works fine if the array is hard coded

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to pass the array to the Draggable Vue component. The array generating dynamically from the inside loop but getting the error
**Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "list". Expected Array, got String with value "arrOne"**
while assigning the array to **:list**

array rendering and assigning script:

```
     <draggable
      class="list-group mttr_kt-block"
     :list="'arr'+item.code"  //here output of item.code is **One** , final array will **arrOne**
     group="tasks">

     </draggable>
```

The above codes throwing the exception and not working as expected but if I assign hard coded array as following its working fine:

```
     <draggable
      class="list-group mttr_kt-block"
     :list="arrOne"  //this hard coded **arrOne**
     group="tasks">

     </draggable>
```

Note: the array **arrOne** already declared inside Vue scripts, no issue with declartion.

Thanks in advance for your help. Please please let me know if additional information is needed from my side.

Comment: The result from: 'arr'+item.code is going to be String
and list is experting an Array.

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes it's turned to string but how can I keep it's as array and pass it as array to :list. could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume `arrOne` and other arrays are defined in `data()`. If so, you can use these:

```html
<draggable
   class="list-group mttr_kt-block"
   :list="getArray(item.code)"
   group="tasks">
</draggable>
```

```js
data() {
   return {
      arrOne: [1, 2],
      arrTwo: [3, 4],
   };
},
methods: {
   getArray(name){
      return this.$data['arr' + name];
   }
},
```